# Unable to read application.yml in Condition class

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have this class

```
@Service
@Conditional(MyCondition.class)
public class Class1 implements AcknowledgingMessageListener<String, GenericRecord> {

  @Value("#{'${audit.module}'}")
  private String xyz;
```

Here is `MyCondition`

```
@Configuration
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties("audit")
public class MyCondition implements Condition {

  @Value("#{'${audit.module}'}")
  private String ss;

}
```

The problem is in `MyCondition` `@Value` is unable to read the value from from application.yml.

Comment: Ofcourse it is, as it isn't a bean (nor should it be) and it is consulted very early on in the process (before any binding is going to happen). So that won't work, you might be able to use the `Environment` to obtain the value.

Comment: can you pls share some example on what r u saying?

Answer (score 0):

`MyCondition` is not a spring managed bean when you use it as a `@Conditional`. So you can not use `@Value` inside `MyCondition`. However there are some workaround.

You can set `String ss` as `static` and add one setter value with `@Value`.

```
@Component
public class MyCondition implements Condition {

    private static String ss;

    @Value("${audit.module}")
    public void setSs(String ss) {
        MyCondition.ss = ss;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

But this value will be set after `Class1` has been created, so at the time on validating `@Conditional` ss will be null.

But I think you will need to use the value of `ss` inside the `matches` method. So inside the `matches` method you can access property values with `ConditionContext`

```
public class MyCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        System.out.println(context.getEnvironment().getProperty("audit.module"));
        return true;
    }
}
```